# Multiple lines on regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have a html file from a website and I work with a regex to search for words and write these words to a document.
I have this text:

```
<div class="scrollable " style="height: 200px;">
        <div>
            <p>CO-Schrank: nicht ben&ouml;tigtes ausbauen</p>
<p><strong>________________________________________________________________________</strong></p>

<p><strong>==&gt;&nbsp; wird nicht mehr ben&ouml;tigt!<br /></strong>z-B.: IUC</p>

<p>CO-Management in Gen. 2 implementieren</p>

<ol>
<li>Ausbau der PCI-Karten aus ZKA-PC in CO-PC- PC-Sys 02 TP 55, 56, 61 sind noch Profibus im ZKA-PC ==&gt; in CO-PC- PC-Sys 02 greift dann auf CO-PC f&uuml;r Datenaufzeichnung =&gt; Betrieb wieder aufnehmen</li>

<li>Ausbau der IUC</li>

<li>Testaufbau am CO-PC f&uuml;r den CO-Algorithmus und Datenspeicherung</li>

<li>Gen. 2 in CO-Management implementieren- pro Pr&uuml;fling 3 Min. (3 Min. x 48 HG x 10 Messungen)&nbsp;= 1440 Min. = 24 h- Messzeit 1-2 Min.</li>

</ol>


</div></div>
```

Now I want all the text in the `<div>.... </div>` too.
I wrote this code but it is not working:

```
Match description = Regex.Match(line, "^<div class=\"scrollable \"^(.*?)$div>", 
    RegexOptions.Multiline);//multiple line

if (description.Success)
{
    //Console.WriteLine(status_id.Groups[1].Value);
    System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\\Webasto\\csv-"+zahl+".txt");
    file.WriteLine(id.Groups[1].Value + ";4;4;" + subject.Groups[1].Value + ";" + due_date.Groups[1].Value+";NULL;"+status_id.Groups[1].Value+";"//+assigned.Groups[1].Value
        +";"
        +priority.Groups[1].Value+";NULL;"+autor.Groups[1].Value+";0;"+created_on.Groups[1].Value+";"+start_date.Groups[1].Value+";"+done_ratio.Groups[1].Value+";"+hours.Groups[1].Value
        +";NULL;"+id.Groups[1].Value+";1;2;0;"+closed.Groups[1].Value+";");
    file.Close();
}
```

Comment: Never use Regex to parse XML/HTML.

Comment: Please use a HTML parser.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's well known that you should use xhtml parser instead of regex.

Anyway, you can use regex if you know what is the character set used in your html. In case you still want to use a regex, then you can use a regex with the single line flag like this:

```
(?s)<div>.*?<\/div>
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/qK1eQ6/1)**

Or using a regex trick:

```
<div>[\s\S]*?<\/div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a misunderstanding of what [`MultiLine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions(v=vs.110).aspx) means (I don't blame you, I have to think twice every time I use regex). `MultiLine` means that every line (ended with `\n`) is treated on its own.

You need `SingleLine`, which treats the whole string as if it was one line.

<sub>Side note: it is a bad idea to use Regex to parse HTML. Use a decent HTML parser instead.</sub>

Comment: True. I always thought singleline was a horrible name for what actually means "dot matches all". Especially since you can have singleline and multiline mode active at the same time.

Comment: Yes, horrible naming convention.